# @testing-library/react-hooks calls setTimeout two times

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-testing-library, react-hooks-testing-library

Here is my custom React-hook.

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

function useInterval({ callback, interval, delay }) {
  const savedTimerId = useRef<NodeJS.Timeout>()

  useEffect(() => {
    const loop = () => {
      const res = callback()
      const nextIteration = () => {
        savedTimerId.current = setTimeout(loop, interval)
      }
      if (res instanceof Promise) {
        res.then(nextIteration)
      } else {
        nextIteration()
      }
    }
    let delayedTimerId: NodeJS.Timeout
    if (!delay) {
      loop()
    } else {
      delayedTimerId = setTimeout(loop, delay)
    }
    return () => {
      // @ts-ignore
      clearTimeout(savedTimerId.current)
      if (delayedTimerId) {
        clearTimeout(delayedTimerId)
      }
    }
  }, [callback, interval, delay])
}

export { useInterval }
```

And here is the unit test

```js
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks'
import { useInterval } from '../useInterval'

describe("Test scenarios for 'useInterval' hook", () => {
  jest.useFakeTimers()

  it("Should call 'callback' once", () => {
    const callback = jest.fn()
    const interval = 10000
    const params = { callback, interval }
    renderHook(() => useInterval(params))
    expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.any(Function), interval)
  })
})
```

But that's the output

```
Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

Expected number of calls: 1
Received number of calls: 2
```

I debugged this snippet. I found that before `useInterval` invocation something has already triggered `setTimeout`.
[image: debug result]

Seems like `setTimeout` has been called internally. What am doing wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're absolutely right that `@testing-library/react-hooks` is calling `setTimeout` under the hood, and you can confirm this with:

```js
jest.useFakeTimers()
renderHook(() => {})
expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
```

You're probably better off focussing on how many times `callback` is called, rather than `setTimeout`:

```js
afterEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
  jest.useRealTimers();
});

describe("Test scenarios for 'useInterval' hook", () => {
  it("Should call 'callback' immediately", () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers()

    const callback = jest.fn()
    const interval = 10000
    const params = { callback, interval }
    renderHook(() => useInterval(params))

    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })

  it("Should call 'callback' repeatedly", () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers()

    const callback = jest.fn()
    const interval = 10000
    const params = { callback, interval }
    renderHook(() => useInterval(params))

    jest.advanceTimersByTime(interval * 2)

    // Expect 3 calls: 1 immediate call and 2 interval calls:
    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3)
  })
})
```